# Why not letrec as fix?

Tags: scheme, letrec, fixpoint-combinators

In the paper *[Fixing Letrec: A Faithful Yet Efficient Implementation
of Scheme’s Recursive Binding Construct](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~dyb/pubs/fixing-letrec.pdf)* by Dybvig et al. it is said that (emphasis mine):

> A theoretical solution to these problems is to restrict `letrec` so
>   that its left-hand sides are unassigned and right-hand sides are `lambda`
>   expressions. We refer to this form of `letrec` as `fix`, since it amounts to
>   a generalized form of fixpoint operator. The compiler can handle `fix`
>   expressions efficiently, and there can be no violations of the `letrec`
>   restriction with `fix`. Unfortunately, restricting `letrec` in this manner is not an option for the implementor **and would in any case reduce the generality and convenience of the construct**.

I have not scrutinized the R5RS report, but I have used `letrec` and the equivalent "named `let`" in Scheme programs and the unfortunate consequences mentioned in the paper are not clear to me, can someone enlighten me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With equational syntax,

```
letrec x = init-x
       y = init-y
  body....
```

the restriction is that no RHS `init...` expression can cause evaluation of (or assignment to) any of the LHS variables, because all `init...`s are evaluated while all the variables are still unassigned. IOW no `init...` should reference any of the variables directly and immediately. It is OK of course for any of the `init...`s to contain lambda-expressions which can indeed reference any of the variables (that's the purpose of `letrec` after all). When these lambda-expressions will be evaluated, the variables will be already assigned the values of the evaluated `init...` expressions.

The authors say, to require all the RHSes to be `lambda`-expressions would simplify the implementation, because there's no chance for misbehaving code causing premature evaluation of LHS variables inside some RHS. But unfortunately, this changes `letrec`'s semantics and thus is not an option. It would also prohibit simple use of outer variables in RHSes and thus this new cut-down `letrec` would also be less general and less convenient.

---

You also mention named `let` but it is *not* equivalent to `letrec`: its variables are bound as-if by `let`, only the looping function itself is bound via `letrec`:

```
(let ((x 1)(y 2))
  (let g ((x x) (y x))
    (if (> x 0) (g (- x y) y) (display x)))
  (display x))
01
;Unspecified return value

(let ((x 1)(y 2))
  (letrec ((g (lambda (x y) 
                (if (> x 0) (g (- x y) y) (display x)))))
     (g x x))  ; no 'x' in letrec's frame, so refer to outer frame
  (display x))
01
;Unspecified return value
```

Comment: So, by generality/convenience loss, it simply meant that if you restrict yourself to lambdas on the RHS, you cannot do something like : (letrec ((x 3) (y (f 4)) (z (lambda (a b) ...)) (z x y))

Comment: @Skeptic yes, exactly, because you reference an undefined (here) variable `f`, which thus must be defined at some outer scope; and it is not inside any lambda expression. And even as simple a value as `3`.

Comment: But that is only because the standard requires to check that the RHS variables are not used before entering the body, if we forfeit that ability, we can have both lambdas and simple expressions in a letrec implemented without set! right ?

Comment: @Skeptic LHS vars can't be used in init (RHS) expressions unless behind `lambda`. But other vars and direct values can be used. That's what we have right now anyway.

Comment: @Skeptic but the article says, the implementation leads to non-optimized code. *Were* only lambdas allowed, the implementation would be optimized. But disallowing other vars and simple values (only allowing lambda-exprs) changes semantics (and is inconvenient - instead of `3` we'd have to write `(lambda() 3)` and call it accordingly). So they propose analyzing the bindings and sorting them out into different categories. The lambda-exprs then can be implemented in optimized way, without setting any temporaries, since there's no danger apriori.

Comment: Oops, I meant the LHS variables. What I was asking myself is : is it only because we want to check that the variables are properly used that we can't optimize all cases (inluding constants and free variables).

Comment: @Skeptic AFAICT, "optimize" means directly plug the RHS expressions into letrec's env.frame bindings' value slots. No temporaries, no intervening `set!`s. But then if there's an invalid use of an LHS var in some RHS expr, we're screwed. And if by chance we aren't, we shouldn't allow it anyway. That's all.

Answer (score 3):

The [R5RS letrec restriction](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%_idx_132) says something like these are in violation:

```
(let ((x 10))
  (letrec ((x x))
    x))

(letrec ((y (+ x 5)) 
         (x 5)) 
  (list x y))
```

Thus, it's not specified what would happen and it would certainly not be portable Scheme. It may evaluate to `10` and `(5 10)`, the implementation might signal an error or you get an undefined value that might result in an error getting signaled. I have tested Racket, Gambit, Chicken and Ikarus and not one of them signal anything in the first case and they all evaluate to an unspecified value. Ikarus is the only one that returned `(5 10)` in the latter while the others all got contract errors since an unspecified value as argument violates +'s contract. (Ikarus always evaluates operands right to left)

The [R[567]RS reports](http://scheme-reports.org/) all state that if all expressions are lambda expressions you have nothing to worry about and I think that is the clue. Another is that you should not try to shadow like you would do with (named) let.

There is a follow up on the original paper that is entitled [Fixing letrec (reloaded)](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~dyb/pubs/letrec-reloaded.pdf) that has macros that implements the "fix".